# browserHistory.push(..) from Redux action changes URL but doesn't trigger re-render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm trying to do a redirect using React Router from a Redux action creator following a `Fetch` request.

I'm using the `browserHistory` approach to push from the action creator, like so:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
...
browserHistory.push('/summary');
```

This is giving me two problems:

**1) History `basename` is not being prefixed.**

When I configured the router history, I set a `basename` value:

```
useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
    basename: '/foo'
});
```

However the `browserHistory.push('/summary')` isn't prefixing the `basename` to the URL. I was under the impression from the History docs (https://github.com/reacttraining/history#using-a-base-url) that it would prefix.

As a temporary workaround for the first issue, I just hardcoded my `basename` into the `push`. Which game me my next issue.

**2) The URL is updated in the browser, but the page does not re-render.**

If I refresh the page after the `push` has happened, the page then renders the correct route, but it seems that the push doesn't trigger a state change to force a render.

I did come across this [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux), but reading the docs, it sounds like it shouldn't be necessary to do what I'm after:

> This library is not necessary for using Redux together with React
>   Router. You can use the two together just fine without any additional
>   libraries. It is useful if you care about recording, persisting, and
>   replaying user actions, using time travel. If you don't care about
>   these features, just use Redux and React Router directly.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I'm sure it's just something I'm missing rather than a bug.

I'm currently using:

- Redux v3.6.0
- React Router v3.0.0
- History v3.3.0

Answer (score 1):

In order to reload your page on an url change, the page component needs to receive the history or location props from react-router.
so add one or another in your props.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was an error in the page before the move.
It was an error related to lifecycle.
After correcting the error, we confirmed normal operation.
Be especially careful with componentWillUnmount.
Otherwise, look at routerReducer and syncHistoryWithStore.